# String logic error in C++

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, gdb

I am writing a program that will evaluate race conditions using bit manipulations and then will also eliminate these race conditions using semaphore locking/unlocking.

I run the program fine with "./raceTest 5 6 3 6 unlock". All of the output used to come out fine. But now it crashes with unlock arg.

My program crashes when I try to compile it with these args as well: ./raceTest 5 6 3 6 lock (or any args with "lock" for that matter)

This is as far as the output goes with a "lock" command. It crashes this way for both now... even though it was not crashing for "unlock" and was displaying everything correctly.

```
./raceTest 5 6 3 6 lock
lock
nBuffers is 5
mWorkers is 6
sleepMin is 3
sleepMax is 6
randarray 4 
randarray 3
randarray 6
randarray 3
randarray 4
randarray 4
Segmentation fault
```

I have tried to use gdb and when I ran the program, I get this error from gdb

```
Starting program: /mnt_nfs/home3/ugrad3/ariley/Desktop/cs361/hw5/raceTest
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003156430265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Can someone please tell me what this means? It was working earlier. But now it is not working and I didnt do anything to it...

```
// raceTest program
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/sem.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>

#if defined(__GNU_LIBRARY__) && !defined(_SEM_SEMUN_UNDEFINED)
/* union semun is defined by including <sys/sem.h> */
#else
/* according to X/OPEN we have to define it ourselves */
union semun
{
int val;                // value for SETVAL
struct semid_ds *buf;   // buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET
unsigned short *array;  // array for GETALL, SETALL 
struct seminfo *_buf;   // buffer for IPC_INFO
};
#endif 

static int sem_id = 0; 
static int sem_semvalue();
static void del_semvalue();
static int semaphore_p();
static int semaphore_v();

using namespace std; 

// struct for the threads 
typedef struct thread
{
int nbuffers; 
int ID; 
double sleepTime; 
int semID; 
int mutexID; 
int *buffer; 
int nReadErrors; 
} Thread_data; 

void *worker(void *targ) 
{ 
cout << "In worker function" << endl; 
// cast back to a struct variable to use 
Thread_data *data = (Thread_data*) targ; 

int errors=0; 

for (int i=0 ; i < data->nbuffers; i++) 
{
    // READ the value of buffers at that thread's ID, starting from current ID 
    int read = data->buffer[data->ID]; 
    usleep(data->sleepTime); 
    // see if the value changed after sleeping 
    int secondRead = data->buffer[data->ID]; 
    if (secondRead != read)
    {           
        cout << " Worker " << data->buffer[data->ID] << " reported change from " << read << " to       secondRead " << secondRead;
        cout << " in buffer " << i << endl; 
        errors ++; 
    }

    read = (read + data->ID) % (data->nbuffers); // next read

    usleep(data->sleepTime); 
    secondRead = data->buffer[read]; 
    if (secondRead != read)
    {           
        cout << " Worker " << data->buffer[data->ID] << "reported change from " << read << " to secondRead " << secondRead;
        cout << " in buffer " << i << endl; 
        errors ++; 
    }

    // write operations to do 
    read = (read + data->ID) % (data->nbuffers);
    usleep(data->sleepTime);
    // add to the buffer array, or the WRITE
    data->buffer[read] = secondRead + ( 1 << (data->ID - 1) );
}
data->nReadErrors = errors;  // update 4. 
pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
int i; // handle all command line arguements
int nBuffers = 0; 
int mWorkers = 0; 
int sleepMin = 0; 
int sleepMax = 0; 
srand(time(NULL));
key_t key = IPC_PRIVATE; 
int rErrors = 0; 
int wErrors = 0; 

// parse command line arguments 
// USAGE: raceTest nBuffers nWorkers sleepMin sleepMax [ randSeed ] [ -lock | -nolock ]
for (i=1 ; i<argc-1 ; i++)
{
    // Check input 
    string s = argv[i]; 
    int num = atoi( s.c_str() ); // UPDATE 5 
    //cout << "argv at " << i << " is " << num << endl; 

    if (num == 0)
    {
        cout << "USAGE: raceTest nBuffers nWorkers sleepMin sleepMax [ randSeed ] [ -lock | -    nolock ]" << endl; 
        cout << "Exiting..." << endl; 
        exit(-1);
    }
}
string s = argv[i++]; 
cout << s << endl; 

// set variables to command line arguments
// nBuffers has restrictions 
nBuffers = atoi(argv[1]);
if ( nBuffers <= 2 || nBuffers >= 32)
{
    cout << "nBuffers is the wrong size. Exiting" << endl; 
    exit (-1); 

    if (nBuffers != 3 || nBuffers != 7 || nBuffers != 11 || nBuffers != 17 || nBuffers !=5
        || nBuffers != 13 || nBuffers != 19 || nBuffers != 23 || nBuffers != 31 || nBuffers !=   29)
    {
            cout << "nBuffers must be prime. Exiting" << endl; 
            exit (-2); 
    }
}

mWorkers = atoi(argv[2]);  cout << "nBuffers is " << nBuffers << endl;
sleepMin = atoi(argv[3]);  cout << "mWorkers is " << mWorkers << endl;
sleepMax = atoi(argv[4]);  cout << "sleepMin is " << sleepMin << endl;  
cout << "sleepMax is " << sleepMax << endl;

int buffers[nBuffers]; 
double randWorkers[mWorkers]; 

// initialize the arrays 
for (int i=0 ; i<nBuffers ; i++)
    buffers[i] = 0; 

for (int i=0 ; i<mWorkers ; i++)
{
    // generate random number between sleepMin and sleepMax 
    int temp = rand() % (sleepMax - sleepMin + 1) + sleepMin; 
    randWorkers[i] = temp; 
    cout << "randarray " << randWorkers[i] << endl;
}

// sort the numbers in decreasing order 
for (int i=0 ; i<mWorkers ; i++)
{
    for (int j=0 ; j< mWorkers ; j++)
    {
        if (randWorkers[i] < randWorkers[j])
        {
            cout << "here" << endl;
            // simple sorting 
            double temp = randWorkers[i];
            randWorkers[i] = randWorkers[j]; 
            randWorkers[j] = temp;  
            cout << randWorkers[i] << " "; 
        }
    }
}
// other sorting method 
//sort (randWorkers, sizeof(randWorkers), greater<double>);

// create an array of M structs and populate each with values needed 
// for the threads 
Thread_data threadVals[mWorkers]; 

for (int i=0 ; i<mWorkers ; i++)
{
    threadVals[i].nbuffers = nBuffers; 
    threadVals[i].ID = i+1; 
    threadVals[i].sleepTime = randWorkers[i]; 
    threadVals[i].semID = -1; 
    threadVals[i].mutexID = -1; 
    threadVals[i].nReadErrors = 0; 
    threadVals[i].buffer = buffers;
}

// create an array of M (threads) where each runs the 
// worker() function 
pthread_t tid[nBuffers];

for (int i=0 ; i<mWorkers ; i++)
{
    // don't do any locking 
    if ( strcmp (s.c_str(), "nolock") == 0)
    {
        // pass a pointer to one of the structs 
        int value = pthread_create (&tid[i], NULL, worker, &threadVals[i]); 
        if (value != 0)
        {
            perror ("thread creation failed");  
            exit(-3); 
        }
        else 
            cout << "successful creation for " << tid[nBuffers] << endl; 
    }

    // use semaphores for the locking 
    else if (strcmp(s.c_str() , "lock") == 0)
    {
        /*cout << "B-----" << endl; 
        int sem_id = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT|0666); 
        if (sem_id < 0)
        {
            perror ( "Cannot create sem_id"); 
            exit(-5); 
        }
        cout << "A-----" << endl; */
        ;
    }
}

// wait for all of the threads to finish 
for (int j=0 ; j<mWorkers ; j++)
{
    pthread_join(tid[j], NULL); 
}

for (int i=0 ; i< nBuffers ; i++)
{
    int size = 2^ mWorkers - 1; 
    if (buffers[i] == size)
        break;  // this particular index is the same 

    cout << "Bad bits for buffer[" << i <<"] = " ; 
    int diff = size ^ buffers[i]; 
    for (int j=0 ; j <mWorkers  ; j++) 
    {
        // perform a binary OR and then binary AND
        int position = (diff) & (1<<j); 
        //cout << buffer[position] << W" ";
        if (position)
            cout << j << " " ; 
        wErrors++; 
    }
    cout << endl; 
}

// figure the total number of read errors 
for (int i=0 ; i<mWorkers ; i++)
    rErrors = rErrors + threadVals[i].nReadErrors; 

cout << "Total Errors: " << "read errors: " << rErrors << " write errors " << wErrors << endl; 
return 0;
}
```

EDIT:: 
This is what I got when I did the bt, I am afraid I dont really understand what this stuff means...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000315643471a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000315643471a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003156431bd2 in atoi () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004010a5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at raceTest.cpp:171
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000003156431bd2 in atoi () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
#2  0x00000000004010a5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at raceTest.cpp:171
171             nBuffers = atoi(argv[1]);
(gdb)
Initial frame selected; you cannot go up.
(gdb) print nBuffers
$1 = 0
```

SECOND EDIT: No matter if Im just threading for collisions or using semaphores. The only change I made was changing the array parameter from nBuffers to nWorkers, and then testing the output of the rand to see if it was producing undefined behavior.

```
[ariley@bert hw5]$ ./raceTest 5 6 3 6 lock
5
6  
3
6
5beforenBuffers is 5
mWorkers is 6
sleepMin is 3
sleepMax is 6
value of temp4
randarray 4
value of temp6
randarray 6
value of temp3
randarray 3
value of temp5
randarray 5
value of temp4
randarray 4
value of temp6
randarray 6
successful creation for 6300416
In worker function
successful creation for 6300416
successful creation for 47840834492736
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: When it crashes in the debugger type `bt` to see the stack.  That will hopefully help you narrow it down.

Comment: If you look at the function call stack (by using the `bt` command) you will see where in your code the exception happens. Walk `up` the call stack to your code and examine the values of the variables. At the very least, edit your question to include the function call stack, and point out where in *your* code the problem is.

Comment: It crashes at this line: nBuffers = atoi(argv[1]);

Comment: That function call, and the error in the debugger (an exception being thrown from the `std::string` class it seems), *and* the output from the program, none of those things match each other.

Comment: Also note that you are using a non-standard feature: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Regarding the crash you get in the debugger, it's because you run your program *without* arguments. See the arguments to the `main` function? It says `argc=1`. When in a debugger, you use the `run` command to run your program, but the arguments to the `run` command is the arguments to your program, so you should run it like `run 5 6 3 6 lock`

Comment: The output is different almost everytime I run it. Sometimes it actually goes through to worker function and starts the Reading and Writing of the buffer array. But most times, its just that. I also have been updating quite a bit.

Comment: I will keep working at it.

Comment: If you get different behavior on each run, then you seem to have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Do you get any warnings when compiling? If not, try adding more warnings with the compiler flags `-Wall -Wextra`. Try to read and understand what the warnings tell you, they are often a sign of you doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: The only warnings I receive are the ones from the sleeps in the worker function. The usleep() function complains that I am passing a double when it wants an int.

Comment: So going through gdb with the cmd line args listed, it works for the nBuffers line, but then crashes on line 200 where I do the rand % (sleepTime...) operations saying I have arithmetic errors. However, printing out the value of temp, everything prints fine.

Comment: And what is the value of `i`? What is the values of `sleepMin` and `sleepMax`? `(sleepMax - sleepMin + 1) + sleepMin` isn't zero?

Comment: no its printing out the correct range of values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am in a really sore mood right now. So im going to get some sleep and come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on __cxa_throw.

Answer (score 2):

```
pthread_t tid[nBuffers];
```

should be

```
pthread_t tid[mWorkers];
```

You don't initialise tid[] array unless the parameter set is 'nolock' (not 'unlock'), and therefore the pthread_join(tid[i], NULL) is called with an invalid param.

Mark.

Comment: That is a good point. Something I definitely overlooked. I looked up pthread_create but I do not understand how the values of tid are defined. My output that I am running has 2 consecutive values of 6300416 for tid and then one really large on 47840834492736. Then a seg fault occurs.

Comment: Yes, because, as I said: "You don't initialise tid[] array unless the parameter set is 'nolock' (not 'unlock')". Run with "5 6 3 6 nolock", and it'll run... if ( strcmp (s.c_str(), "nolock") == 0)

Comment: Actually, thats exactly what I meant when I said it was running earlier. Thats what I had for input. But it started seg faulting for lock or nolock.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me what this means?

It means that you did (an equivalent of) this:

```
char *cp = NULL;
std::string s(cp);  // throws logic_error
```

Comment: The only path that calls pthread_create () to create the worker threads (and therefore have a valid entry in tid [] in the call to pthread_join ()) is when you call with 'nolock'...